# How to add a section in checkout above shipping method

Tags: magento2.3.1, checkout-page

[image: I want to set a session variable in checkout if a particular product is in the cart list and then display a section based on that to display a section (fetch in js/view/shipping.js) or a step in checkout.]

I want to add a section in mentioned location. but its showing in shipping method section and i need a seperate section
Checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="our-delivery-component" 
                                                                  xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" 
                                                                      xsi:type="string">
                                                                    Magento_checkout/js/view/option-delivery</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your new message above the shipping form. Welcome!</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

option-deliver.js

```
define(
    [
        "uiComponent",
        'ko'
    ],
    function(
        Component,
        ko
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Checkout/option-delivery'
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this._super(); //you must call super on components or they will not render
            }
        });
    }
     );
```

delivery-option.html

```
<div class="message warning"><span >testing</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to custom the region of the shipping step, you should take a look the shipping step template

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

I'm going to add a new region to this part. This region will be outside the Shipping method region. In `web/template/shipping.html`

```
......
<li data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <each args="getRegion('delivery-option-form')" render="" />
</li>
......
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="delivery-option-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">delivery-option-form</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="delivery-option" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/delivery-option</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Js component: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/delivery-option.js

```
define(
    [
        "uiComponent",
        'ko'
    ],
    function(
        Component,
        ko
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/option-delivery'
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Html template: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/option-delivery.html

```
<div class="message warning"><span >Testing Option Delivery</span></div>
```

[image]

**[NOTE]**
When putting the new area outside the shipping method form, you will need to build more logic to work with server. This will take more time, but worth trying.

Comment: Its getting displayed in shipping section/step and  also in Review & Payments section on top.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Added more logic to shipping.html template.

Comment: How Can I add url of cms page in html file or do I need to use phtml file ?? Also My block is displaying below shipping methods and not above image ?? what can be a issue for this ??

Comment: I need to add some custom field on this area & store the values in order level, do you have any code or any ?